# Run a script only when a hidden div (display:none) is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to run a script only when a hidden div (display:none) is active.

When press "radio button" display "div1" with the fake loader and after 3 seconds display another div called "my_div".

But if the user don't press the "radio button", the random text on "my_div" still appears.

I need to fix this, only show this random text "my_div" if the user press the radio button. So, when user press "radio button" display "div1" with fake loader and after 3 seconds, display another div (already working), if not press the button, nothing happens (don't run the random script).

Working:
https://jsfiddle.net/zto6gv1c/3/

This is my project:

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

var r_text = new Array();
r_text[0] = "Disponível";
r_text[1] = "Indisponível";
r_text[2] = "Disponível";
r_text[3] = "Indisponível";
r_text[4] = "Disponível";
r_text[5] = "Disponível";
r_text[6] = "Indisponível";
r_text[7] = "Disponível";
r_text[8] = "Indisponível";
r_text[9] = "Disponível";
r_text[10] = "Indisponível";
r_text[11] = "Disponível";
var i = Math.floor(7 * Math.random())

document.write(r_text[i]);

window.onload = function() //executes when the page finishes loading
{
  setTimeout(func1, 3000); //sets a timer which calls function func1 after 2,000 milliseconds = 2 secs.

};

function func1() {
  document.getElementById("my_div").className = "show";
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Deseja chegar a disponibilidade do produto?</p>

<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" /> Sim

<div id="div1" class="hide">CHECANDO</div>

<div id="my_div" class="hide"></div>
```

Comment: Please add your code as a Stack Snippet by using the button at the top of the textarea, next to the image button.

Comment: What do you mean "when the div is active" ?

Comment: First do something about 
document.write(r_text[i]); because this is going to clear whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Let me know if I am nearby.

```
function show2() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(func1, 3000); 
}
```

Then, replace document.write with below

```
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = r_text[i];
```

Then replace your window.onload code with below

```
window.onload = function() //executes when the page finishes loading
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(document.getElementById('div1').style.display != 'block'){
            func1();
        }
    }, 3000); //sets a timer which calls function func1 after 2,000 milliseconds = 2 secs.
};
```

Comment: Thanks !! Working !

Answer (score 0):

Oke so **WHEN**  class hide has display none - you want to run some other code ?

You can check the visibility this way:

```
var isVisible = document.getElementsByClassName("hide")[0].style.display == "block";
if(isVisisble){
   this thing is hiden
}else{
   this thing is not hiden
}
```

We use getElementsByClassName because you put it on a class with the name 'hide' - there is only one of these elements present so we use [0] to get the first one (the only one) then we use the style.display to check the value.

Comment: Logic:
When press "radio button" display "div1" with the fake loader and after 3 seconds display another div called "my_div". But if the user don't press the "radio button" the random text on "my_div" still appears.

I need to fix this, only show this random text "my_div" if the user press the radio button.
So, when user press "radio button" display "div1" with fake loader and after 3 seconds, display another div (already working), if not press the button, nothing happens (don't run the random script).

Radio Button
"div1" = Fake Loader
"my_div" = Random Text